# finding L in a table

Tags: python, algorithm

i have a matrix that has dot(.) or star(*) only. i want an algorithm that finds starts in a L shape.each L made by 5 stars and can have common stars with another L. some example:

```
[['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*']]

in this matrix we have 8 L.(here's two Ls:[(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (3,1)], [(1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (4,1)])
```

```
[['*', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '.', '.'],
]

in this matrix we have 2 L
```

```
[['*', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '*', '.', '.', '.'],
]

just 1 L
```

and here's my code but i think it has bug.

```
L_counter = 0

def find_L(star_row, star_column):
    global my_list
    global L_counter

    if my_list[star_row+1][star_column] == '*':
        if my_list[star_row+2][star_column] == '*':
            if my_list[star_row+3][star_column] == '*':
                if my_list[star_row+3][star_column+1] == '*':
                    L_counter += 1
                    

my_list = [['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
           ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
           ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
           ['*' ,'*', '.', '*', '*'],
           ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
           ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*'],
           ['*', '*', '.', '*', '*']
           ]

for row, i  in enumerate(my_list[:-3]):
    for column, j in enumerate(i[:-1]):
        if j == '*':
            find_L(row, column)

print(L_counter)
```

Comment: So you want to detect right angles starting from a cell and moving down neighbors and then across? Loop through each cell, ignoring the last row and last columns and go down and make sure you don't have any neighbors to the left and if there is one below it, check if that one has one below it, else, move right. If you branch, you will have to account for each branch.

Comment: What makes you think it has a bug? Was there a particular matrix that it failed on?

Comment: `find_L` checks for only four stars, should be five

Comment: it would be a lot cleaner with numpy arrays. In fact, it will boil down to a one-line convolution. Let me know if you want an example

Comment: @tylerstoney there is a site that we sent code there.they tested the code and said it's not right without giving reason. :(

Comment: @Marat thanks.but we want work without any library

Comment: @Marat I think the fifth star is checked by the `if j == '*':` in the calling code.

Comment: ah, righ. It does

Comment: @user3386109 oh.thanks.i forgot that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as elegant as it should be, but the best I could make it without numpy:

```
# approach: look for the vertical 4-bar plus one star in the 'foot'
sum(foot=='*' and all(row[col_num]=='*' for row in rows)
    for rows in zip(*(my_list[j:] for j in range(4))) 
    for col_num, foot in enumerate(rows[-1][1:])
)
```